# Proper way to handle Nullable References and RequiredAttribute on model binding

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-core-3.0, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

In my web-api controllers I post query model (for paging, filtering and sorting) for my entities.
I have nullable references enabled solution-wise (all projects in csproj)
The base classes are:

```
public class SearchFilter
{
    public string? q { get; set; } // <-- This should indicate that the "q" property is optional
    public bool? fullResults { get; set; } // <-- This should indicate that the "fullResults" property is optional
}

public class Query<TFilter> where TFilter : SearchFilter, new()
{
    public int skip { get; set; }
    public int take { get; set; }
    public List<SortDescriptor> sorting { get; set; } = new List<SortDescriptor>();
    public TFilter? filter { get; set; } // <-- this indicates that the property "filter" is optional
}
```

So, for instance, a Query model for users would be:

```
class UserFilter: SearchFilter
{
    bool? is_activated {get;set;} // etc.
}

class UserQuery: Query<UserFilter>{
}
```

When my client posts this request json

```
{
    "skip":0,
    "take":25,
    "sorting":[{"field":"id","desc":true}]
}
```

The request completes successfully as expected. The "filter" property is optional (as indicated by the nullable property), and indeed the "filter" property is missing from the above json

When I try to filter my data by providing another value

```
{
    "skip":0,
    "take":25,
    "sorting":[{"field":"id","desc":true}],
    "filter": {
        "is_avtivated": true
    }
}
```

I get a bad request response

```
{
  "errors": {
     "filter.q": ["The q field is required."]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|fb9d87a2-47080df6ddd0a9dc."
}
```

What is going on here? Is not supposed "q" to be optional? I read that enabling nullable-references in c#8 will automatically put `[Required]` attributes to non-nullable properties, but as it seems here it also puts `[Required]` attributes **to nullable properties too**!

- Is this a bug in .net core?
- Or is this expected?
- And how should I make my request work?

The request is clearly correct (it worked perfectly before enabling nullable references) and very clear. The code is also very clear.

"A `filter` is optional. If a `filter` exists, the `q` property of the filter is also optional".

This is what the code reads to.

As a note, I feel very frustrated that I don't have control over which property is actually required and which is not (nullable references **is not** the way to declare this intention). I use nullable references only for the warnings, to spot potentially problematic pieces of code. I would expect that enabling this feature wouldn't alter the application's behavior in any level.

Comment: Did you use asp.net core 3.0?I would get error in this line:`public TFilter? filter { get; set; }` by using your code.And it would works fine if using `public TFilter filter { get; set; }` . Could you share the action about how to receive the json?

Comment: @Rena Yes this is asp.net core 3.0 with nullable references enabled. The line you mention shouldn't throw an error as long as the TFilter generic type is a class (not a struct). The TFilter filter{get;set;} should throw a warning when having nullable references enabled and TFilter is class.